# XML - External DTD : The content of Element type must match

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm New to XML and learner ! XML with XSD is more comfortable than DTD ! im facing on error solving a DTD extension.

Question :
A person will have dependents and the dependents can be spouse and children or only spouse. A person can have more than 1 child.Generate XML and DTD

From that Schema Im able to write DTD! named "**person.dtd**" an external DTD that will be linked to XML file .,

[person.dtd][2]
and XML as .,
[person.xml][1]

The error I'm Facing is that!

> Error:     Public ID: null    System ID:
>   file:/home/p11422/person_given.xml    Line number: 11    Column
>   number: 12    Message: The content of element type "spouse" must match
>   "(spouse_name,spouse_age)".

anyone please help me to get rid of this error!
this is person.dtd ->

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT person (name , age , address , dependents)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT age (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT address (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dependents (spouse,children?)>
<!ELEMENT spouse (spouse_name , spouse_age)>
<!ELEMENT spouse_name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT spouse_age (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT children (child+)>
<!ELEMENT child (cname , gender , cage)>
<!ELEMENT cname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT gender (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT cage (#PCDATA)>
```

this is person.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE person SYSTEM "person.dtd">
<person>
   <name>Deepak</name>
   <age>28</age>
   <address>Vijayawada</address>
   <dependents>
     <spouse>
         <spouse_name>padma</spouse_name>
         <spouse_age>26</spouse_age>
     </spouse>
    </dependents>
</person>
```

Comment: Please provide input (DTD, XML) as code in question, not as linked illustrations. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @potame for responding ! i've added the code snippet above ! please have a look ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Pro tip: It's much easier to help debug an issue if you put the actual code in the question instead of just images.

Since I'm on my phone and unable to easily reproduce the issue, I'm going to make a best guess.

I believe the issue you're having is that the content model for the `dependents` element is non-deterministic. In other words it's ambiguous; the parser can't determine which `spouse` is being matched without looking ahead.

Try changing your declaration from:

```
<!ELEMENT dependents (spouse|(spouse,children))>
```

to:

```
<!ELEMENT dependents (spouse,children?)>
```

This means exactly one `spouse` followed by zero or one `children`.

This doesn't seem to match the error you're getting, but it's the only thing I'm seeing wrong. The declaration/usage of `spouse` seems to be ok.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Haley , I've changed the declaration and updated my question ! but i'm getting the same error !  i've added the DTD and XML code blocks please do have a look . Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, the input being read by the validator is not the input you think.  The input you show is valid against the DTD you show, and neither xmllint nor RXP issue any error messages about the 'spouse' element.  (Both do complain about the stray blank at the beginning of the DTD.)